# Debugging the newpage tab on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

If you have an extension that is set as the new tab provider of Chrome (e.g. chrome://newtab), then the developer tools (inspect), etc. seem to be disabled. Is there a way to enable them for debugging purposes?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Devtools is working for me as it should be.

Comment: Sounds like an extension from ExtensionInstallForcelist or devtools is disabled in chrome://policy

Comment: @wOxxOm: Ah yes, that's right. It's an enterprise plugin. Thanks for the insight!